# Копирование файлов с Windows в Debian (из-под Debian)

Tags: linux, windows, debian, ssh

Доброго времени суток!

Вопрос до боли короткий, но довольно нетривиальный, раз ответ на него мне не удалось найти на просторах гугла.

Есть утилита PSCP для копирования файлов через SSH. С копированием файлов из Linux в Windows из-под Windows все понятно - прописываешь параметры и путь. В копировании в обратную сторону (нужно именно из-под машины на Debian) есть вопрос - как прописывать путь к папке с файлами?
То бишь команда полностью будет `pscp -P 22 Username@IP:/Users/username/Desktop/folder_name .`, но если в системе Windows есть разделение на диски, как прописать конкретный, чтобы, к примеру, из диска D:\ шло копирование? Лишнее двоеточие не сломает синтаксис команды?

Comment: _С копированием файлов из Linux в Windows из-под Windows все понятно_: у вас Linux установлен на виртуальную машину?

Comment: @Денис RPi4 с Raspbian. SSH сервер стоит на ней, машина с Windows подключается к нему через PuTTy

Comment: и дальше я правильно понимаю, что вы хотите из Windows передать файлы на Linux?

Comment: @Денис да. Хочу из-под Linux скопировать файлы из Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для того, чтобы скопировать конкретный файл из `Windows` в `Linux` с помощью `pscp.exe` используйте следующую команду:

```
pscp.exe C:\Users\Denis\Documents\squid.msi denis@192.168.2.65:/home/denis/testfolder/squide.msi
```

Если вы хотите скопировать несколько файлов, то:

```
pscp.exe C:\Users\Denis\Documents\*.docx denis@192.168.2.65:/home/denis/testfolder/
```

Если вы хотите на компьютер с `Windows` (опять же с помощью pscp.exe) скопировать файлы с `RPi4` то используйте команду:

```
pscp.exe denis@192.168.2.65:/home/denis/dotnet-runtime-5.0.1-linux-arm.tar.gz C:\Users\Denis\Desktop\
```

А вот если вы находясь на RPi4 на `Linux` хотите по `scp` передать файлы на компьютер с Windows, то у вас ничего не получится. Насколько я помню, в Windows нет никакого аналога `SCP`, который бы слушал порт и передавал данные. За исключением, если вы на `Windows` создадите общую папку которую монтируете по `smb` внутри `Linux`.

Ну, и могу ещё предложить:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/lang:ru

*WinSCP - это графический клиент SFTP (SSH File Transfer Protocol) для Windows с открытым исходным кодом. Он также поддерживает [устаревший] протокол SCP (Secure Copy Protocol). Предназначен для защищённого копирования файлов между компьютером и серверами, поддерживающими эти протоколы.*